# How to remove lines in npp?

Tags: notepad++

Hello I have text like this :

> Number,Name,IDclient,Workhours

and I need to remove the first 3, and leave only the **Workhours**.

How can I do that in NPP?

Comment: I would do it with find and replace. Is there a reason not to?

Comment: The title is misleading. It's not really removing lines - you only remove parts of each line.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex-based search/replace will remove all except the last column of your CSV file:

Find what: `.*,`

Replace with: `<nothing>`

Search mode: **Regular Expression**

Option `. matches newline`: **OFF**